# How to separate my demo website from my personal Github page

Tags: github, github-pages

So I have a .github.io personal github website and currently inside the website, I have one page that serves as a demo page for my web application project(its a simple single page application).

Now I want to separate that page and create a new repository for it so that making changes to it does not affect my personal website. However, I still want to navigate to that page with .github.io/.

Currently, I have a repository for my demo page and an index.html, but doing the above gives me 404 page not found.

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your demo page in a `repoName` repository in a **gh-pages** branch.

Your demo will reached at url `yourName.github.io/repoName`.

In the case you have filenames prefixed with . or _, you can add an empty `.nojekyll` file to instruct Github pages not to ignore them, like for processing a Jekyll site.